# How to make density plot grid with groups based a column of list data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, density-plot

I have a data frame called df_norm, which is with different parameters, and the last column 'val' is a list of data. I aim to build a density plot grid for 'val' column with pairwise of delta_mu and sd_inflation group. Each cell in column 'val' should be a density plot.

This line of code cause the problem "ggplot2::geom_density(data = df_norm, ggplot2::aes(x = df_norm$val))" In general, the density plot is based on a vector of data, but each cell in the 'val' column is a list of data. How to input x here? I'm confused about how to build the plot on this structure. I also transposed the 'val' column as n_val, but it seems not able to connect with other parameters for the facet_grid group. Please advice. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

params_grid <- expand.grid(
  Distribution = c("norm","weib"),
  Alpha = .05,
  Sim = 1,
  nboot = 100,
  SampleSize = 3000,
  Prop = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5,.75,.9),
  mu1 = 0.01,
  sd1 = 1,
  mu2 = c(1, 2, 4, 8),
  sd2 = c(1, 2, 4)
)

df_n_w = data.frame(
  dist = params_grid$Distribution,
  prop = params_grid$Prop,
  mu1 = params_grid$mu1,
  mu2 = params_grid$mu2,
  sd1 = params_grid$sd1,
  sd2 = params_grid$sd2,
  delta_mu = params_grid$mu2 - params_grid$mu1,
  sd_inflation = params_grid$sd2/params_grid$sd1,
  n1 = floor(params_grid$Prop * params_grid$SampleSize),
  n2 = params_grid$SampleSize - floor(params_grid$Prop * params_grid$SampleSize)
)
 
df_norm = data.frame(df_n_w[df_n_w$dist == 'norm',])

df_norm$val = lapply(seq_len(nrow(df_norm)),
                     \(i) with(df_norm[i,],
                      c(rnorm(n1, mu1, sd1),
                        rnorm(n2, mu2, sd2))))

n_val = as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df_norm$val),nrow = params_grid$SampleSize))
 
delta_mu_labels <- paste0('Delta mu = ', c(0.01, 0.99, 1.99, 3.99, 7.99))
names(delta_mu_labels) <- c(0.01, 0.99, 1.99, 3.99, 7.99)

sd_inflation_labels <- paste0('SD Inflation ', c(1, 2, 4),"x")
names(sd_inflation_labels) <- c(1, 2, 4)

p1 = plotly::ggplotly(
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
    ggplot2::geom_density(data = df_norm, ggplot2::aes(x = df_norm$val)) +
    ggplot2::facet_grid(delta_mu ~ sd_inflation, 
                labeller = labeller(delta_mu = delta_mu_labels,
                                    sd_inflation = sd_inflation_labels)) +
    ggplot2::theme_classic(14) +
    ggplot2::ylab("Population Density") +
    ggplot2::xlab("Values") +
    ggplot2::theme(legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(10))
  )

print(p1)
```